# pandas formation index looping

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How to I do the following type of process using a `for` loop in `pandas` (indexing the the location index of the column)

z1 = math.sqrt( (df.loc[0,"A #1"] - a_mean[0])**2 + (df.loc[0,"B  #1"] - b_mean[0]) **2)

z2 = math.sqrt( (df.loc["A #2"] - a_mean[0])**2 + (df.loc[0,"B  #2"] - b_mean[0]) **2)

```
    input: 

a_mean = [ 1, 2, 3]
b_mean = [1, 2, 3 ]

     x#1     A #1     A #2   A #3    B#1    B#2   B#3

0     1       2       3       4       5     6      7
1     1       2       3       4       5     6      7

output: 
       (z list [1]   (z list [2)
 z1 0  answers         answers
 z2 1     ?               ?
```

Comment: do you mind to write df, a_mean and the expected output?

Comment: can you please provide a more detailed example?

Comment: Maybe all you need is `df['z'] = math.sqrt((df['A'] - a_mean[0])**2 + (df['B'] - a_mean[0]) **2)`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
z = []
for i in range(1,n):
    z_p = []
    for s in range(0,3):
        z_p.append(math.sqrt( (df.loc["A #"+str(i)] - a_mean[s])**2 + (df.loc[s,"B #"+str(i)] - a_mean[s]) **2))
    z.append(z_p)
```

Another possibility is to use [dataframe.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), though you might need multiple calls if you have a lot of functions to apply to each column.

Comment: thank you answer my question. now i thinking how can i add in the list of list, so that every is look like  in group                                                                    

  z =[ [ z1 ,z1 ,z1], [z2,z2,z2] ]

Comment: z = []
for i in range(1,n):                                                                                                
    for s in range (3):
    z.append(math.sqrt( (df.loc[s, "A #"+str(i)] - a_mean[s])**2 + (df.loc[s,"B #"+str(i)] - a_mean[s]) **2))